# Actualizar valores de DataFrames desde otro DataFrame en Python en un lazo For

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, diccionarios

Por favor desearía saber como puedo actualizar dos `DataFrames` `df1` y `df2` a partir de otro `DataFrame` `df3`. Todo esto lo realizo dentro de una lazo `for` que iteran sobre todos los elementos del `DataFrame` `df3`

```py
for i in range(len(df3)):
   df1.p_mw = ...
   df2.p_mw = ...
```

Los `DataFrames` iniciales `df1` y `df2` son los siguientes:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['GH_1', 10, 'Hidro'],
                    ['GH_2', 20, 'Hidro'],
                    ['GH_3', 30, 'Hidro']],
                    columns= ['name','p_mw','type'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['GT_1', 40, 'Termo'],
                    ['GT_2', 50, 'Termo'],
                    ['GF_1', 10, 'Fict']],
                    columns= ['name','p_mw','type'])
```

El `DataFrame` del cual quiero actualizar los datos es:

```py
df3 = pd.DataFrame([[150,57,110,20,10],
                    [120,66,110,20,0],
                    [90,40,105,20,0],
                    [60,40,90,20,0]],
                    columns= ['GH_1', 'GH_2', 'GH_3', 'GT_1', 'GT_2'])
```

Como se puede apreciar el `DataFrame` `df3` contienen datos de la columna correspondiente `p_mw` para ambos `DataFrames` `df1` y `df2`. Además el DataFrame df2 tiene un elemento con nombre GF_1 para el cual no se tiene actualización y debería permanecer igual.

Luego de la actualización para la ultima iteración la salida deseada  es la siguiente:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['GH_1', 60, 'Hidro'],
                    ['GH_2', 40, 'Hidro'],
                    ['GH_3', 90, 'Hidro']],
                    columns= ['name','p_mw','type'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['GT_1', 20, 'Termo'],
                    ['GT_2', 0, 'Termo'],
                    ['GF_1', 10, 'Fict']],
                    columns= ['name','p_mw','type'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No creo que un `for` sea la mejor opción, muchas veces el proceso es muy lento y esto es algo que juega en contra si tienes miles de datos. Para fscilitar las cosas los *DataFrames* tienen un método llamado `apply()` que sirve para *aplicaarle* una operación.

Por otra parte me doy cuenta que lo que quieres es que `df1` y `df2` tengan los últimos datos de `df3` que por lógica son los más actualizados.

Para obtener los últimos datos del `df3` podemos apoyarnos del método `iloc`, el cual nos permite escoger filas y columnas en base a sus índices.

```py
act = df3.iloc[-1,:]
```

Toda operación con un *DataFrame* devuelve un *DataFrame* por lo que si queremos acceder a sus valores tendríamos que hacer, por ejemplo, `act["GH_1"]`.

Ahora vamos a usar el método `apply()` para poder cambiar el valor de la columna `p_mw`, este método recorre el *DataFrame* por columnas, pero nosotros queremos que lo haga por filas para así poder saber si el dato de la columna `name` es igual al que se tiene en la variable `act` y de esa forma cambiar el valor de la columna `p_mw`, esto se podría simplificar si solo se reemplaza la columna, pero decidí pensar que los datos pueden no estar ordenados.

```py
#actualizamos el df1
df1["p_mw"] = df1.apply(lambda x: act[x["name"]] if x["name"] in act else x["p_mw"],axis=1)

#actualizamos el df2
df2["p_mw"] = df2.apply(lambda x: act[x["name"]] if x["name"] in act else x["p_mw"],axis=1)
print(df2)
print(df1)
```

##### Resultados

**df1**

|  | name | p_mw | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | GH_1 | 60 | Hidro |
| 1 | GH_2 | 40 | Hidro |
| 2 | GH_3 | 90 | Hidro |

**df2**

|  | name | p_mw | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | GT_1 | 20 | Termo |
| 1 | GT_2 | 0 | Termo |
| 2 | GF_1 | 10 | Fict |

Comment: Muchas gracias @Christian. Una pregunta adicional, cual es la razón para emplear `-1` en el método `iloc` en lugar de colocar en este caso `3`.

Comment: @ChristianRueda como dije, lo hago pensando que el *DataFrame* puede variar (tamaño) y al poner  `-1` directamente accedemos al ultimo elemento